# Error: Cannot convert 'data' to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, opera

I am hosting a  SPA on S3, it works in IE, Chrome and Opera version 25 but not in Opera version 12.17.
On app load I make a request out to our API using  **angular $http.get** , when I look in the network traffic , it does not show these  request ever being made.

```
var config = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ accessToken };

$http.get(url, { headers : config })
   .success(function(data, status) {
   $rootScope.info = " In success callback";
   callback(transformResponse(data));
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
   $rootScope.info = " In error callback";
   callback(data.error);
 });
```

I get the following error in the console.

```
Error: Cannot convert 'data' to object
    <anonymous function: f.error>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:72
    <anonymous function: then>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:100
    <anonymous function: then>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:100
    <anonymous function: then>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:100
    <anonymous function: then>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:101
    <anonymous function: $eval>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:111
    <anonymous function: $digest>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:108
    <anonymous function: $apply>([arguments not available])@http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js:112
```

---

**Its looks like it might be a CORS issue, if I place a resource under the same domain as my application and make a request for that resource then it works as it should.
What is it about OPERA 12.17 that causes this issue and what  is a possible work around?**

Comment: Can you please show your config object?

Comment: @AhsanAyaz added it in the edit

Comment: remove .min from Angular's path. It will give you more details about the error.

Comment: @NewDev you mean like so ? http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js . I still get the same error message with the same amount of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a CORS issue. Opera 12.17 seems to be very restrictive when it comes to CORS. I moved the app and all the necessary resources into one domain and it works as it should. Note * this issue only happens with Opera 12.17 , later versions seem to work.